# Converting an xsl:apply-templates into a string value to use as an if parameter

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, dita, dita-ot

I have this piece of code, modified from the DITA-OT original distribution:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]" mode="in-this-section-chapter-list">
    <fo:block margin-left="6em">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:call-template name="insertVariable">
                <xsl:with-param name="theVariableID" select="'Chapter with number'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="theParameters">
                    <number>
                        <fo:inline>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('map-id', @id)[1]"
                                mode="topicTitleNumber"/>
                        </fo:inline>
                    </number>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

I am trying to only execute/print this mini-toc, when this is a **Part** that has **Chapters** as child nodes (see below), but not when it is only a **Part** without any Chapters, in a book like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bookmap>
<part>
    <chapter/>
    <chapter/>
    <chapter/>
</part>
<part/>
<part/>
<part/>
<part/>
<appendix/>
</bookmap>
```

So in this case, only the first **<part>** would execute/print this.

I thought that passing the value from **<xsl:apply-templates select="key('map-id', @id)[1]" mode="topicTitleNumber"/>** as text, would allow me to add an **if** that basically will test for a value that is not empty, thus executing this. But it has not worked.

I came up with something like this, which is not valid:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]" mode="in-this-section-chapter-list">

<xsl:with-param name="value-number">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('map-id', @id)[1]"
        mode="topicTitleNumber"/>
</xsl:with-param>

<xsl:if test="$value-number!=''">
    <fo:block margin-left="6em">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:call-template name="insertVariable">
                <xsl:with-param name="theVariableID" select="'Chapter with number'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="theParameters">
                    <number>
                        <fo:inline>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('map-id', @id)[1]"
                                mode="topicTitleNumber"/>
                        </fo:inline>
                    </number>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: To say something her at least the key declaration for map-id and the used template with `mode="topicTitleNumber"` is required.  A  guess  would be that this template generate some xml. Than you can't use that as text without an xslt extension.

Answer (score 2):

For the template to match only `part` that contain `chapter`, change `match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]"` to `match="part[chapter][contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]"`.

You might no longer need the `[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]` if the predicate is going to be true for every `part` that you're interested in.  And you really don't want it if it's going to be false for any of the `part` that you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to add an OR so that you pick up chapter if you want the minitoc at the chapter level.